# Public DNS Name

Tags: azure-container-instances

According to the following link I should see a public DNS name with my ACI Container:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/32983720-automatically-assign-dns-name-to-instance

However, no DNS name is not created.  Here's how I'm creating the container:

```bash
az container create -g ex-rg --name ex-container --image docker.io/repo/example:latest -e somevar=value --ip-address public --location westus

az container show --resource-group ex-rg --name ex-container |grep ip
```

```json
"ipAddress": {
  "ip": "40.112.219.202",
```

```bash
az container show --resource-group ex-rg --name ex-container |grep dns
```

````
"dnsNameLabel": null,```
````

```bash
az --version
```

```bash
azure-cli (2.0.27)
```

I've also tried using terraform (which uses the API), with the same result.

ACI won't be of use to us if we can't use a DNS name.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the dns-name-label parameter from the CLI in order to receive one. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_create) can help and an example is shown below - keeping in mind of course that your dns name needs to be unique.

```bash
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myalpine --image alpine:latest --ports 80 443 --dns-name-label contoso
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for people using docker compose with ACI, you can add a domainname property to any of the services on your docker compose file. Any time you push an image and spin up the instance, Azure will use that domainname.location.azurecontainer.io as the FQDN for your container group. You can then access each containers with that domain name and their respective ports.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Azure Container Instances Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-groups)

It appears you cannot achive this in CLI yet (See the comments section of the above doc)

[image]

Looks like there will be some documentation on how to achive this coming our in the new few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using the ARM template, and yet you still cannot make a custom domain + ssl Cert attached to it. Kinda useless :/, hoping for update soon as there is no proper workaround

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the dnsNameLabel in the ARM template, you can looking it up via

```sh
az container show --resource-group ex-rg --name ex-container | grep -pattern fqdn
```

Grepping *dns* will not show the right result.